# How to clean a CGContextRef prior to drawing?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have a CGContextRef with things drawn inside, and I want to clear it out so that it is empty (all transparent). How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CGContextClearRect`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClearRect) should do the job.